# min function in PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I want to choose the min value in two date ,such as

```
c := min(a,b);
```

It occupy  compiler error :

> Error(20,10): PLS-00103: Encountered
>   the symbol "," when expecting one of
>   the following:
>   . ( ) * @ % & - + /
>   at mod remainder rem     || multiset

I know we can use aggregate function  `Min` in the SQL. I dan't whether there is the similar func i can use i pl/sql?

Comment: The min(expression) function takes `field_name`. Doesn't it?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In PLSQL, the `least` function returns the smallest value in a list of expressions.

Answer (score -2):

`LEAST("ColumnName", _NumberOfRows)`

Example: For the Minimum 5 Rows = `LEAST(Price,5)`

Comment: This is NOT how to get the minimum 5 rows.  This will give you the lower value between price and 5.

Comment: To get the five items with the lowest price, you need to do something like this: `SELECT * FROM (select * from items order by price asc) WHERE ROWNUM <= 5
ORDER BY ROWNUM ASC`